# Kafka Scala: How to move val into try catch block

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

I'd like to move:

```
val kafkaPartitionOffset = kafkaConsumer.endOffsets(consumedPartitions.asJava)
```

into a `try catch` block like so:

```
val kafkaPartitionOffset : SomeClass = 
            try {
               kafkaConsumer.endOffsets(consumedPartitions.asJava)
            } catch {
              case e: Exception => {
                log.error(s"${consumerGroupId} Could not get Kafka offset", e)
                None
              }
            }
```

But I'm having trouble on what the `SomeClass` should be. I've tried `Map[TopicPartition, Long]` but it says `Type mismatch`. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

**Update:** I've also tried `Any` but I'm unable to do a `kafkaPartitionOffset.get(topicPartition)` below (`get` is highlighted red with error message `cannot resolve symbol get`:

```
        for((topicPartition,OffsetAndMetadata) <- mapTopicPartitionOffset){
          
          val bbCurrentOffset =  OffsetAndMetadata.get(topicPartition)

          // latest offset
          val partitionLatestOffset = kafkaPartitionOffset.get(topicPartition)

          // Log for a particular partition
          val delta = partitionLatestOffset - bbCurrentOffset

          topicOffsetList += delta.abs

        }
```

Comment: `OffsetAndMetadata` is a class, not an instance variable, so unclear what `.get()` is trying to do here

Comment: @OneCricketeer dude, how did you figure out that it's a class? because of naming? it comes from the for actually.

Comment: @AminMal https://kafka.apache.org/31/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/OffsetAndMetadata.html - I dont think Scala allows you to shadow class names with local variables

Comment: @sojim2, you can also move all your logical code (which gets topic partion, etc,.) into the try block if you wanted to.

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I got you, it doesn't matter, the variable named the same `OffsetAndMetadata' shadows the class with the same name, it's in the local scope.

Comment: @OneCricketeer No It actually allows, might be weird but take a look at this: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/AminMal/uMtzL2adSSqbE1nMmu2H1g/13

Comment: @AminMal that's a great idea, put it all in `Try` and can do `get` on `kafkaPartitionOffset`

Comment: @OneCricketeer, you're right that was my next task, I'm trying to get the offset per partition and not sure how to get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this:

```scala
val x = try { 
  throw new RuntimeException("runtime ex")
  "some string"
} catch { case _: RuntimeException => 2 }
```

The compiler needs to know the type of `x` before runtime, since `x` can be used somewhere else in your code, right? So the compiler says:

> "Hmm, what is a type that this literal "some string" is of that type,
> and also, literal 2 is of that type?"

So it looks for the lowest super-type of both String and Int, which is `Any` in this case! so `val x: Any = ...`. Now I'm not aware of what this expression `kafkaConsumer.endOffsets(...)` returns, in case it returns `Option[T]`, then SomeClass would also be `Option[T]` since you're returning None in the catch block, and if not, do not use None there just because nothing else would fit, there are better approaches to exception handling.
But anyways, Scala provides some utility types to avoid this kind of try catch as much as possible, I would recommend you to use `Try` in this case.

```scala
val kafkaPartitionOffset: Try[Whatever-endOffsets-returns] = 
  Try(kafkaConsumer.endOffsets(consumedPartitions.asJava))
```

By the way, the title of the question doesn't match the actual question, please consider changing the title :)

Comment: Thank you for this! I should've mentioned I tried `Any` without any luck. The `get` function wouldn't work for `kafkaPartitionOffset`. Updated post & title!

Comment: @sojim2 that's because type `Any` does not have a method `get`. think about it this way, what would happen if the code throws exceptions, the value would be None. and what do you expect from None to give you when you want to get a topic partition from it?